# model5-names.bst from elsarticle.cls gives "&" in text citation when \citet{} is used instead of "and"

Tags: bibtex, citing

APA style requires in text citation to replace "&" with "and" when the authors' names are cited outside the parenthesis in the text, for example:

correct

He, Zhang, Zhou and Chen (2009)

incorrect

He, Zhang, Zhou & Chen (2009)

However, model5-names.bst from elsarticle.cls gives "&" in text citation when \citet{} is used instead of "and".

I need help to modify model5-names.bst to give me the proper in text citation format.

Thank you.

Comment: Given your earlier questions on this site, you clearly need a fully APA6-compliant bibliography style -- and `model5-names` is not such a style. Question: Why don't you simply use the [apa6](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa6) package and the `apa6` bibliography style and be done with it? Why, instead, try to "fix up" a bibliography style that was probably never meant to be  complaint with APA bibliography style requirements?

Comment: Thank you again @Mico for taking time to answer. The reason I don't use apa6 package is because I wanna have my LaTeX code ready and compliant to elsarticle.cls in case the manuscript gets accepted. In other words, I wanna keep all formatting from elsarticle (figures, tables, sections, etc.), but it's annoying that although Elsevier's supplied bst template says "APA" in it's comments, in reality it is not. Therefore, the problem lies with the style of citation which supposed to be APA, but it's not.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this turns out to be one of the easier questions you've posted so far.

- In the modified version of `model5-names.bst` (you've called the modified copy something like `mymodel5.bst`, right?), locate the function named `format.full.names`.
- In this function, locate the string `bbl.and`. Replace this string with `"and"`. Note the double quotes.
- Save the file `mymodel5.bst`.
- Be sure to load the `natbib` package with the option `longnamesfirst`. *The solution prposed here will not work unless this option is specified.*
- Rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Remarks: (i) As indicated above, this solution works only if natbib's `longnamesfirst` option is set. If this isn't to your liking, I'm afraid I have no advice on what else might be done. (ii) The solution proposed here won't be to APA style if you use `\citep` instead of `\citet` to cite a given entry for the first time in a document.

Comment: As always, many thanks @Mico for responding my call. Unfortunately, the modification you proposed doesn’t replace "&" when `\citet` is used with citekey that contains two authors, although it works well when there are three or more authors. Luckily I found a workaround by using `{\renewcommand\&{and}\citet{citekey}}` instead of `\citet` and think this will do the trick. The only concern I have is in case I need to send my raw tex file to the editors and their technicians run the code with the style of their own, i.e., whether the renew command I use will somehow interfere. But thank you again.

Comment: @Gaijin - I'm afraid I've reached the end of my competence in this matter.  If the answer doesn't work for you, just let me know and I'll delete the answer. Or, consider writing a new answer, in which you explain your method.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I would recommend not to delete the answer, since it works partially and might be helpful to others. Thank you once more.